# How can I find out which digital libraries include a given journal?

Tags: journals, online-resource, literature-search, digital-libraries

When I am looking for a journal online, I have to do search for it in every electronic database one by one.

Is there an easy way to find which electronic databases provide that journal?

I am doing legal research.

Comment: [Google scholar?](http://scholar.google.com)

Comment: Google Scholar does not show this information. I want to read Journal X, for example and for this purpose I want find out which electronic database, Heinonline or Westlaw or another eletronic database, includes that journal...

Comment: Why do you need a list of databases including the journal - why can't you just search for the journal in Scholar and go to whatever database it takes you to? Some context (i.e.. what your overall goal is) might help clarify this question.

Comment: Could you please find for me "International Construction Law Review" using Google Scholar, for example? Can you see any info about electronic database in the results? I cannot. Maybe it's my fault.

Comment: That particular journal doesn't seem to be in mainstream databases, so it's not indexed by Scholar. But generally, in Scholar, if you click on "All N versions", it will give you a list of links to the various sites it's available on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Worldcat.org](http://worldcat.org) will give you this information. Search for the journal by name, click on it in search results, and look under "Find a copy online".

For example, "International Construction Law Review" appears to be available in two digital libraries:
[image: Worldcat screenshot]

Comment: Thank you very much. I was using that site only for printed materials. I did not think about looking for electronic sources there. Useful information.